# FutureWarning: specifying 'categories' or 'ordered' in .astype() is deprecated; pass a CategoricalDtype instead

Tags: python, pandas

The warning in the title is produced by pandas 0.21.0 on Python 3.6.3 with code such as `pd.Series(["a", "b", "b"]).astype("category", categories = ["a", "b", "c"])`. How exactly is one supposed to write this now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `CategoricalDtype` mentioned in the warning is available as [`pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype.html). So, you can write `pd.Series(["a", "b", "b"]).astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories = ["a", "b", "c"]))`.

Comment: don't understand why it was made more complicated/longish?

Comment: @randomSampling Yes, it's poor design.

Answer (score 4):

```
pd.Categorical(pd.Series(['a','b','b']), categories = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Also you can use the ordered parameter to create a categorical hierarchy

```
result = pd.Categorical(pd.Series(['a','b','b']), categories = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered = True)
```

Update to convert to Series dtype

```
pd.Series(result)
```

Comment: This code creates a Categorical object, not a Series with a Categorical dtype.

Comment: You are right. Set above equal to result and convert to series with pd.Series(result)

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer the lack of repetition in the following:

```py
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "b"]).astype("category").cat.as_ordered()
```

And prove it

```py
s.max()
```

doesn't generate an exception.

(It will in recent pandas if not orderred.)

Comment: But then you can't specify the categories, as you can in the original code.